# How to Read and Write SoundPool object into Parcel?

Tags: android, android-activity, parcelable, soundpool

Beginner here. I have a class with a SoundPool object in it. I would like to have the class implement Parcelable so that its instance can be passed between activities (so that I only load the sounds once).

But I am facing a problem in writing the SoundPool object into the parcel. May I know if it is possible at all? (Maybe SoundPool does not implement Parcelable?)

```
public class SoundSamples { // implements Parcelable{

SoundPool sound;
AudioManager am;
int soundId[] = new int[4];
Context ctxt;

public SoundSamples(Context context) {
    ctxt = context;
}

public void makeSound() {
    Context context = ctxt;

    sound = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundId[0] = sound.load(context, R.raw.c4, 0);
    soundId[1] = sound.load(context, R.raw.cs4, 0);
    soundId[2] = sound.load(context, R.raw.d4, 0);
    soundId[3] = sound.load(context, R.raw.ds4, 0);
}

public SoundPool getSound() {
    return sound;
}

public int[] getSoundId() {
    return soundId;
}

/*
private SoundSamples(Parcel in) {

    // STUCK HERE
    sound = in.readParcelable(null);
    soundId = in.readArray(Integer);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<SoundSamples> CREATOR
= new Parcelable.Creator<SoundSamples>() {
    public SoundSamples createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new SoundSamples(in);
    }

    public SoundSamples[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SoundSamples[size];
    }
};

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {

        // AND STUCK HERE 
    out.writeIntArray(soundId);
    out.writeParcelable((Parcelable)sound,0);
}
*/
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Do point out if this is the correct way to do things at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely do **not** want to convert a `SoundPool` to a `Parcel` and send it between activities. This is totally inefficient.

Just store the `SoundPool` object in a `public static` variable and you can access it from all your activities.

For more information, see my answer to [Intent and Parcelable object Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264678/intent-and-parcelable-object-android/12266509#12266509)